# run .jar program to read from 2 file and calculat the result to another file

Tags: linux, command

i need to ran this ideacalc.jar to read from file1 first key hex and from file2 second key hex and send result to another file3

than to help about an command linux for this

i have java in /root/jre/java  version 8-121

i can run it with /root/jre/bin/java -jar ideacalc.jar

the program when i run it in windows i have this

[image]

this is the web site for this program

http://lpb.canb.auug.org.au/adfa/src/IDEAcalc/

Comment: any help please